# Convert columns of data.frame from lists to vectors

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have a data.frame created from a list "y" using the code

```
map_dfr(y, ~as.data.frame(t(.x)))
```

The format works for me, but each column of the dataframe is itself a list, rather than the vector I'd like it to be. What can I do to flatten out each list such that I preserve the structure of my dataframe, but change the format of each column?

EDIT: Here's a small bit of the data in its current format. What I'm looking to do is unlist each variable into a vector so it takes the normal data.frame format.

```
structure(list(member_id = list("A000055", "A000361", "A000367", 
"A000369", "A000210", "B001256", "B000013", "B001279", "B001269", 
"B001282"), name = list("Robert B. Aderholt", "Rodney Alexander", 
"Justin Amash", "Mark Amodei", "Robert E. Andrews", "Michele Bachmann", 
"Spencer Bachus", "Ron Barber", "Lou Barletta", "Andy Barr"), 
party = list("R", "R", "R", "R", "D", "R", "R", "D", "R", 
    "R"), state = list("AL", "LA", "MI", "NV", "NJ", "MN", 
    "AL", "AZ", "PA", "KY"), district = list("4", "5", "3", 
    "2", "1", "6", "6", "2", "11", "6"), cook_pvi = list(
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL), vote_position = list("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), dw_nominate = list(
    0.361, 0.331, 0.649, 0.376, -0.297, 0.584, 0.387, -0.123, 
    0.277, 0.485), bill_num = c("S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", 
"S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47", "S47"), bill_title = c("Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", 
"Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", 
"Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", 
"Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", 
"Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013", 
"Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Oops, apologies, I had a section of the data created, but I forgot to include it. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, this is what you want :

```
y[] <- lapply(y, unlist)
```

This will convert the data into normal data.frame form.

```
str(y)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ member_id    : chr  "A000055" "A000361" "A000367" "A000369" ...
# $ name         : chr  "Robert B. Aderholt" "Rodney Alexander" "Justin Amash" "Mark Amodei" ...
# $ party        : chr  "R" "R" "R" "R" ...
# $ state        : chr  "AL" "LA" "MI" "NV" ...
# $ district     : chr  "4" "5" "3" "2" ...
# $ vote_position: chr  "No" "Yes" "No" "Yes" ...
# $ dw_nominate  : num  0.361 0.331 0.649 0.376 -0.297 0.584 0.387 -0.123 0.277 0.485
#$ bill_num     : chr  "S47" "S47" "S47" "S47" ...
# $ bill_title   : chr  "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013" "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013" "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013" "Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013" ...
```

---

If we have list of multiple lengths we can use `unnest` and pass a range of columns.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

z <- y %>% 
       unnest(cols = member_id:district)  %>%
       type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
       arrange(desc(district))
```

We can use  `arrange(district)` to sort them in ascending order.

Comment: For some reason, this is working on the example data I posted, but not with the full data set. When I try it on the full data set of 1,100 rows, I get a list as the output rather than a data.frame.

Comment: @ModalBro Do you have list of multiple lengths? Try `y %>% unnest(cols = member_id:district)`

Comment: That appears to work, but when I try and sort the columns in the data viewer I get the following error that I was getting before:
Error in order(x[[col]], decreasing = identical(dir, "desc")) : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

Comment: I don't have the data so can't really know for sure but maybe try the updated answer.

Comment: It looks like some variables remain as lists, but if I call unlist() on that specific variable and then assign it back, it converts. So I guess that will work for now. Thank you for your help!